# BeforeStep & AfterStep Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I've discovered an issue with the BeforeStep and AfterStep annotations in an ItemReader. I'm hoping someone can give me some clarification.

## What Works:

I have an ItemReader implementation with the following methods:

```
 public class ReaderImpl implements ItemReader<String> {

      @BeforeStep
      public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
         //do before step processing...
      }
    
      @Override
      public String read() {
         //do read...
      }

      @AfterStep
      public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
         //do after step processing...
      }
 }
```

XML configuration:

```
<step id="step1">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="readerImpl" writer="writer" commit-interval="100" />
    </tasklet>
</step>

<bean id="readerImpl" class="package.to.ReaderImpl" scope="step"/>
```

*The above context works just fine, and the BeforeStep and AfterStep methods are being executed properly.*

## **What Does NOT Work:**

When I wrap my ReaderImpl with another bean, spring no longer executes the BeforeStep and AfterStep methods.

Example:

```
<step id="step1">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="synchronizedReaderImpl" processor="processor" writer="writer" commit-interval="100" />
    </tasklet>
</step>

<bean id="synchronizedReaderImpl" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.SynchronizedItemStreamReader" scope="step">
    <property name="delegate" ref="readerImpl" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Because either your `readerImp` is not step-scoped anymore but rather a singleton (depends on your config) if it isn't that, it is because it isn't registered, automatically , as a step-listener anymore because it isn't the actual reader registered.

Comment: @M.Deinum So, the bean with the BeforeStep and AfterStep must be the one defined in the chunk?

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you have a reference to the documentation for this use case?

Comment: The one defined in the chunkc is registered as a listener (and will only work if there are annotations or they implement the interface). The synchronized listener doesn't implement the interface nor the annotations and doesn't delegate either. You can simply register your reader as a listener manually. For information, check the Spring Batch reference guide.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have one small problem with the approach of registering the Reader as a listener. It's that there is not a guarantee the listener will be executed. If a step inherits step1, then listeners are not merged automatically.

Comment: Why would you inherit a step? Not sure what is copied when doing things like that.

Comment: @M.Deinum Inheriting steps provides default values for the child step. The reader,processor,writer,commit-interval can all be defaulted in the parent, and overridden if necessary in the child step. It's actually quite useful.